# Navigate from navigate controller changed toolbar title not only in the next, but also in the previous fragment

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, navigation-drawer, toolbar

In my project I use DrawerLayout and BottomNavigation. DrawerLayout use for some global options, BottomNavigation - for local. But...

I have a problem:
When I opened new fragment using findNavController().navigate  old fragment's title changed same as new fragment title.

My code from new fragment:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        if (args.action == null) {
            binding.toolbar.title = requireActivity().getString(R.string.menu_create_new_action)
        } else {
            binding.toolbar.title = requireActivity().getString(R.string.menu_edit_action)
        }
    }
```

my navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_main"
        android:name="com.smog.bestdeals.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_timers"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_main_to_nav_create_edit_timer"
            app:destination="@id/nav_create_edit_timer">
        </action>


        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_main_to_nav_create_edit_action"
            app:destination="@+id/nav_create_edit_action">
        </action>


        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_main_to_nav_settings"
            app:destination="@id/nav_settings" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_main_to_nav_timers"
            app:destination="@id/nav_timers"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_timers"
        android:name="com.smog.bestdeals.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_timers"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_create_edit_timer"
        android:name="com.smog.bestdeals.ui.timer.CreateEditTimerFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_create_new_timer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_edit_timer" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_create_edit_timer_to_nav_main"
            app:destination="@id/nav_main" />

        <argument
            android:name="timer"
            app:argType="com.smog.bestdeals.data.repository.Timer"
            app:nullable="true" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_create_edit_action"
        android:name="com.smog.bestdeals.ui.action.CreateEditActionFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_create_new_action"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_edit_action" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_create_edit_action_to_nav_main"
            app:destination="@id/nav_main" />

        <argument
            android:name="action"
            app:argType="com.smog.bestdeals.data.repository.Action"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks

P.S. I created this answer, because I was looking for the error for about 1 hour. Perhaps someone will face the same problem, so I decided to add a question and an answer to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Because I used Navigation controller, it use android:label attribute and when I use findNavController().navigate NavController get label from navigation file and auto change title. So, my decision: **delete label attribute from your navigation file**. This is in case you open a new fragment on top of another. My app using three options: above current fragment, BottomNavigationView, NavigationDanwer.